# Pulling a value from related table in a controller

Tags: model-view-controller, foreign-keys, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework for the first time, trying to implement it in a project.

I've got a dropdown list of customers where i'd like to also show customer's company next to customer's name.

Customer and Company tables are related. Here's what it looks like in a Customer model:

```
public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::className(), ['id' => 'company_id']);
}
```

So now i'm forming a dropdown list containing customer's name, email, phone and company name. Name, email, and phone belong to one table, so there's no problem with pulling them together. Here's what it looks like in Customer model:

```
public function getfullInfo()
    {
            return $this->name.' '.$this->phone.' '.$this->email;
    }
```

I don't really understand this framework's logic. How do I pull in Company's name in above code?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Adding "$this->company->name" gives out an error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: try using relation name. may help.

Comment: I think the problem with `$this->company->name` is that sometimes `$this->company` exists (is an object) and sometimes it doesn't, in which case `hasOne()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code:

```
public function getfullInfo()
    {
            return $this->name.' '.$this->phone.' '.$this->email.' '.$this->company['name'];
    }
```

This was so easy and I've wasted so much time on this.